# How to write these without lambda expression?

Tags: haskell, lambda, monad-transformers

I'm turning first version of [this code](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html) to use `StateT L8.ByteString Maybe a`. So far I've turned most functions into this

```
matchHeader :: L8.ByteString -> StateT L8.ByteString Maybe ()
matchHeader prefix = StateT $ \str ->
      if prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
         then Just ((), L8.drop (L8.length prefix) str)
         else Nothing

getNat :: Num a => StateT L8.ByteString Maybe a
getNat = StateT $ \str ->
  case L8.readInt str of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (num, rest)
      | num <= 0        -> Nothing
      | otherwise       -> Just (fromIntegral num, rest)

getBytes :: Integer -> StateT L8.ByteString Maybe L8.ByteString
getBytes n = StateT $ \str ->
  let
    count = fromIntegral n
    both@(prefix, _) = L8.splitAt count str
   in if L8.length prefix < count
        then Nothing
        else Just both
```

But how do I write these without using lambda expression? I've tried some variations. No luck so far.

Comment: You can give the function a name.  You can use the lambda-case extension.

Comment: Why do you want to write them without a lambda expression?

Comment: For learning purposes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `do` notation and state/monad operations more.  For example:

```
getNat :: Num a => StateT L8.ByteString Maybe a
getNat = do
  num <- StateT L8.readInt
  guard (num > 0)
  return (fromIntegral num)
```

EDIT: By request, attempt at `getBytes`:

```
getBytes :: Integer -> StateT L8.ByteString Maybe L8.ByteString
getBytes n = do
  let count = fromIntegral n
  prefix <- state $ L8.splitAt count
  guard (L8.length prefix >= count)
  return prefix
```

While `:browse`-ing `Control.Monad`, I also found the (somewhat new?) function `mfilter`, which could shorten this further, but requires either some point-free-ness or another lambda:

```
getBytes n = do
  let count = fromIntegral n
  mfilter ((>= count) . L8.length) . state $ L8.splitAt count
```

Come to think of it, that can work with `getNat` too:

```
getNat = fromIntegral <$> mfilter (> 0) (StateT L8.readInt)
```